# How to have a click event function start with the last child element and then work it's way up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I creating the game connect 4 and I'm trying to get the colors to stack on top of each other after one color is already selected. (Sorry I'm not the best at explaining things and I'm a novice at coding)

Here is the Javascript/JQuery

```
$('.row:last-child').click(function () {
$(this).css('background-color', 'pink')
counter++
if (counter % 2 === 0) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'pink')
    if ($('.row:last-child').css('background-color', 'pink') || $('.row:last-child').css('background-color', 'black')) {
        $('.row:nth-child')
    }
} else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black')
}
```

})

Here is a link to my HTML
https://github.com/ChizzyEze/Project-1-Connect-4/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Use a CSS class, would make this a lot easier....

Comment: What do you mean by "work it's way up"? you want to subsequently trigger the event handler on the siblings of the clicked element? or what?

Comment: @KevinB I want to trigger the event on the last child element first. When I click again on the same column I want to check to see if it has pink or black if so move to the sibling above it and add the pink (or black)

Comment: Ah, so select all of the elements in that column, reverse them, then select the first blank one. three separate tasks to research.

Comment: Like this? [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqzvmx](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqzvmx) I changed the click event to the column, select all children of the column, exclude any that include a color-class, then simply apply the appropriate class to the last child. This creates the stacking effect you were looking for.

Comment: @Popatop15 yes that's it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var counter = 0;
$('.column').click(function() {
    counter++    
    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).children().not('.pink, .black').last().addClass('pink');
    } else {
        $(this).children().not('.pink, .black').last().addClass('black');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background: silver;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
}

.game {
    border: 7px solid black;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
}
.row {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
}
.column {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   flex: 1;
}

.pink {
 background-color: pink;
}
.black {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Chizzy's Connect 4</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Connect 4</h1>

    <div class="game">
        <div class=" column" id="col0">
            <div class="row" id="col0row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col0row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col0row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col0row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col0row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col0row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col1">
            <div class="row" id="col1row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col1row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col1row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col1row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col1row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col1row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col2">
            <div class="row" id="col2row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col2row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col2row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col2row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col2row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col2row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col3">
            <div class="row" id="col3row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col3row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col3row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col3row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col3row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col3row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col4">
            <div class="row" id="col4row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col4row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col4row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col4row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col4row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col4row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col5">
            <div class="row" id="col5row5"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col5row4"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col5row3"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col5row2"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col5row1"><div></div></div>
            <div class="row" id="col5row0"><div></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class=" column" id="col6">
                <div class="row" id="col6row5"><div></div></div>
                <div class="row" id="col6row4"><div></div></div>
                <div class="row" id="col6row3"><div></div></div>
                <div class="row" id="col6row2"><div></div></div>
                <div class="row" id="col6row1"><div></div></div>
                <div class="row" id="col6row0"><div></div></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="space"></div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```